# Rotating between URLs, how precise would randomly picking from an array be?

Tags: php, html, arrays

thanks for taking the time to read this.

My goal here is to rotate between links, anywhere from 1 link up to, let's say 4.
The easy way to do this, would be to make an array of the links and using php, pick one randomly to display.

While this is pretty easy, and quick to set up, it also has me worried a bit, because it's not really accurate, especially not on a small scale.

Giving you some numbers here, let's say my website gets anywhere from 3000 to 5000 unique impressions a day, how accurate would it be to randomly pick a link from an array for 2, 3 or 4 links to choose from?

If anyone else has an idea on how to make a system that rotates very accurate and evenly, let me know!

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me out :)

Comment: There's also additional random libraries provided to better randomize results: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php https://codeascraft.com/2012/07/19/better-random-numbers-in-php-using-devurandom/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over a lengthy period of time with many impressions, most random functions would be evenly distributed. For a small distribution, the results may be noticeably skewed... but the more

But for perfectly even distribution, nothing beats a straight cafeteria-plate "next-up" array.

Either way, I think you will be satisfied.